# Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.1:build (build-image)

Tags: java, docker, spotify

I m trying to deploy a project but at the end I got this error , I don't know what does it mean or what to do to solve it

```
The requested profile "enable-docker-prod" could not be activated because it does not exist.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:push (push-image) on project myalert-v2-backend: Exception caught: Get https://172.19.47.33:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 172.19.47.33:5000: getsockopt: no route to host -> [Help 1]
```

here's the profiles in the **pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>enable-docker-preprod</id>
        <properties>
            <docker.registry>10.75.6.44:5000</docker.registry>
            <skipDocker>false</skipDocker>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>enable-docker-prod</id>
        <properties>
            <docker.registry>172.19.46.169:5000</docker.registry>
            <skipDocker>false</skipDocker>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>releases</id>
                <name>releases</name>
                <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/</url>
                <snapshots />
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>SRVDEV-ARTFAC-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://172.19.46.238:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>http://172.19.46.238:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
                <name>jcenter</name>
                <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>jcenter-releases</id>
                <name>jcenter</name>
                <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

please help in order to understand what's matter , thank you.

Comment: I can suggest below:

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest,

1. if you want to deploy your artifact into artifactory you need to have distributionManagement tag (refer google for syntax)
2. then run mvn command like. mvn clean deploy -Penable-docker-prod

Note: here  will help you to download dependency jar from configured repository and it nothing to do with deploy.

For deploy your artifact into your artifactory (like artifactory, jfrog) you must have ...i hope these info useful.